# CSS Report display HtmlPage.Window.Eval( "window.print()" ); in Silverlight 5

Tags: html, css, asp.net, silverlight, printing

Has anyone used HtmlPage.Window.Eval( "window.print()" ); to print pages in Silverlight 5.I understand that Silverlight has its own PrintDocument class and support for printing technologies. 
But since our clients upgraded from using HtmlPage.Window.Eval( "window.print()" ); to silverlight 5's print document, they have been having issues with printing and is not usable.
I am planning to still keep the version of Silverlight 5 but use HtmlPage.Window.Eval( "window.print()" ) for printing. We use IE 10. It does not need to work on other browsers.

Can anyone recommend some good videos or tutorials about HtmlPage.Window.Eval( "window.print()" ).Currently it is printing blank pages for me.
What should I look for? 
Is there something in the silverlight.js which tells it to print?
There is css file but all it has is some fonts.
Can someone help me with why the first report wraps. It is cutting off the width of the report after a certain width Is it the width of the report or the font

This is the problem I am having: 
Scrre HtmlPage.Window.Eval( "window.print()" ) does not keep the format
[image]

See screenshot: printDocument 
[image]

See how both of the are so different. One uses HtmlPage.Window.Eval( "window.print()" ) and the other uses PrintDocument

These are the code details for Eval method.

```
 private HtmlDocument        m_HtmlDoc;
            private HtmlElement         m_PrintReport;
            private HtmlElement         m_Div;
            private HtmlElement         m_Table;
            private HtmlElement         m_TR;
            private HtmlElement         m_TD;


this.m_HtmlDoc = HtmlPage.Document;
this.m_PrintReport = this.m_HtmlDoc.GetElementById( "printReport" );

    HtmlPage.Window.Eval( "window.print()" );
```

Report Viewer

body
{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
    font-family: rvConsolas;
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: rvConsolas;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url(EmConsola.eot);
}

## rptViewer

{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

## printReport

{
    visibility: visible;
    font-family: rvConsolas;
    overflow: hidden;
}

td 
{
    font-family: rvConsolas;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 52%;
}

## Page

{
    page-break-after: always
}

Comment: No Comments anyone!!

Comment: This might be helpful.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671023(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @GlennFerrie: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I wish vector printing worked for us. We have our code using Silverlight 5's Print document and vector printing. But its been very unpredictable and unusable. Sometimes blank reports, garbled, unknown print error. After doing some research I came to the conclusion both silverlight and printer driver(post script printer) are responsible. Couldn't really find a fix except forcing it to printBitmap. I am just finding alternatives other than using silverlight 5's print. It has not helped us. Thank you though

Comment: if you're not building a phone app, then you can use something called the HTML Bridge.  Here is a walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359(v=vs.95).aspx DISCLAIMER: I've used this in SL4, never tried it with SL5.It enables you to call a JS function in the HTML page from managed code (Silveright code)

Comment: @Glenn Ferrie: awesome thanks..

Comment: @GlennFerrie: Have you used HTML Bridge for printing? How did you implement page margins. When we use Print Document the PrintDoucmentEventArgs has the printers page margins. Based on that we can get the Printable Page Margin. But when using HTML Print all we do is call Invoke.Print or Eval.Print.